# my script is not reading *.txt file

Tags: php

I have a form which takes two values. One takes a .txt file, the file at which some links are hard coded and a text field which takes a url. When I press submit it takes that url and checks on every link that is on *.txt file. Hope you understand what I am saying if not then please comment I will clarify it. Now I have problems. My code does not work until the file at which links are, is not at my server. I don't how to handle this problem. I have done my search, I also try mysql but that is not ok for me. My script is this:

```
Enter your file :<input type="file" name="ufile" />
Enter your site name :<input type="text" name="utext" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" />
```

Now, my php script is this:

```
$needle = $_POST['utext'];
$file = $_FILES['ufile'];
$new = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$new = array_map('trim', $new);
echo 'Total entries are: '.count($new).'<br />';
$found = array();
$notfound = array();
foreach ($new as $check) {
    echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
    echo "<td>Processing</td> <td>", $check,"</td></tr>";
    $a = file_get_contents($check);
    if (strpos($a, $needle)) {
        echo "<td><font color='green'>Found:</font></td>";
        $found[] = $check;
    } else {
        echo "<td><font color='red'>Not Found</font></td>";
        $notfound[] = $check;
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
}
echo "Matches ".count($found)."<br />";
echo "Not Matched ".count($notfound);
```

Comment: Please clarify what "My code does not work..." means

Comment: my code works only if the .txt file is on the server. If not code will not work also

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you never [read the documentation about how](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) PHP handles uploads in first place? That would make clear that `$_FILES['ufile']` is **array**, so your code cannot work. If you really want to continue writing code without understanding it first, then replace:

```
$file = $_FILES['ufile'];
```

with

```
$file = $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'];
```